# ifstream gives me only 16 elements

Tags: c++, file, iostream, ifstream

my problem is:
Ifstream gives me only 16 elements

Hi there, In my c++ code I have multiple classes. They are:
-Data (Include some numbers)
-Towns (Include at least 2 *Data*-objects (in a vector), and the State name)
-County (Manage the *Town*-objects)

The program should fill the *Town* object with the data of a given file.
The code looks like that:

**COUNTRY.CPP:**

```
Country::Country(string file) {
  ifstream x(file);

  Town t;
  while (x.good()) {
    x >> t;
    this->towns.push_back(t);
  }
}
```

To get deeper -> the „>> t“ looks like this:

**TOWN.CPP:**

```
istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Town& d) {
  is >> d.state>> d.town;
  Data a, b;
  a.SetYear(2011);
  is >> a >> b;

  // Some other code was here - but i think it's not relevant

return is;
}
```

To get deeper -> the „>> a“ looks like this:

**DATA.CPP:**

```
istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Data& d) {
    return is >> d.total >> d.male >> d.female;
}
```

As you saw - the towns are in a given file. The structure in the file repeat over and over again(in total: 11292) and looks like this:

**SOURCE(example)**

```
Baden-Württemberg
Kirchheim am Neckar
5225
2588
2637
5205
2608
2597
Baden-Württemberg
Kornwestheim
31053
15167
15886
31539
15502
16037
```

1st Line: State
2nd Line: Town
3rd-5th AND 6th-8th Line: Data
*REPEAT*

soo... And for some reason the ifstream only gives me 16 elements(16 Towns). Hmmm....

Comment: `Kirchheim am Neckar` -- The `std::string::operator >>` only reads up to the first white space character.  Maybe that's why you are not getting all of your data, or at least this seems to be a flaw in your reading in of the input.  All you would get is `Kirchheim` and not `Kirchheim am Neckar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a `std::string` using the shift operator read just one word. By default words are delimited by whitespaces. As a results the string `Kirchheim am Neckar` will not be read entirely but only `Kirchheim` will be read. When trying to read `am` as an integer the stream will go into failure mode and refuse to read anything until its flags are `clear()`ed.

You probably want to read the town and possibly the state by reading the entirely line. Use `std::getline(stream, str)` to do so. Also, **always** test success of your read operation **after** the read attempt. The idiomatic way to use stream is

```
while (x >> t) {
    ...
}
```